# Prove a real number must be either positive, negative, or zero

Tags: real-analysis

I came up with a few cases about the components of the corresponding Cauchy sequence of a real x, like having all positive rationals, but got stuck to prove with a sequence having mixing positive and negative rationals, but all the negative rationals are in first n positions, and all positive rationals are in the rest. 
How do you prove that? and how do you prove if using my approach?

Update: Limit should not be used here, because in the analysis book I am reading, the section having such question does not introduce about the definition of limit yet, but rather a placeholder notion LIM, such that a real is equal to LIM of a Cauchy sequence, without further say how LIM works. The books continue to introduce basic operations of reals like sum and product using such notion. 
The book I am reading is Analysis I of Tao, FYI.

Comment: It is only vaguely suggested that your approach involves Cauchy sequences to define real numbers.  So you might begin by showing that any *Cauchy* sequence of *rational numbers* which contains both infinitely many positive terms and negative terms must converge to zero in the limit.  Remember that the "first $n$ positions" of a sequence can be dropped without changing the limit.

Comment: The problem is I have not reached to the section about limit, so I cannot use limit as a way to prove.

Comment: How is it you are asking about construction of real numbers using Cauchy sequences without having the notion of limit as presented in first term calculus?  This is the sort of context necessary to give you a helpful response.  Please edit the Question accordingly.

Comment: I know what limit is. But what I am trying to say is from the real analysis book I am reading, the set of all reals is built from scratch. It just has a placeholder notion called LIM, and defines a real x is equal LIM of a Cauchy sequence, without explicitly saying further how LIM operate. I learn basic operations about real like sum and product through the notion, and they all make sense so far. The book suggests to use Cauchy sequence that is positively bounded away from zero to prove, but I haven't find a way to make use of it.

Comment: The title and author of the book you are studying is important context.  You should edit your Question to include that information and thus frame more clearly what difficulty you've encountered.

Comment: This depends *ENTIRELY* on your definitions!  I'd say most books I've seen so far *defines* positive as $> 0$ and negative as $< 0$ and via definition given any $a,b$ exactly one of the following is true: $a<b; a=b; a > b$.  If we look at $b = 0$ there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Here is a closely related Question, drawn from Terence Tao's book: [Is it possible that a positive real number is a limit of some Cauchy Sequence of rational numbers containing both positive and negative numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578045/is-it-possible-that-a-positive-real-number-is-a-limit-of-some-cauchy-sequence-of)

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that such a sequence with a mix of positive and negative numbers has an equivalent Cauchy Sequence which is positively(or negatively) bounded away from 0.

> but all the negative rationals are in first n positions, and all positive rationals are in the rest.

Assuming the positive portion is a Cauchy sequence, you can set all the negative portion to some $\delta \gt 0$ since we have some value of $\delta$ such that $|a_i|>\delta$ for all $i>=1$ (This stems from x being a non-zero real number, which is hence not equivalent to the zero-sequence). You now have a positive Cauchy sequence bounded away from zero, which is equivalent to the example described in the question. And hence a positive real number.

You can use equivalent sequences to prove the whole statement. An outline of the whole proof would go like this:

You can prove that utmost one of the 3 statements is true for a real number $x = LIM_{n \to \inf} a_n$. No two sequences (let alone Cauchy sequences) can be both positively and negatively bound from zero. So we cannot simultaneously have $x \gt 0$ and $x \lt 0$. A positively bound sequence is bounded away from zero. So $x \gt 0$ and $x = 0$ doesn't hold simultaneously. The same holds for $x \lt 0$ and $x = 0$.

We now prove that at least one of the three statements is true. Since real numbers are well defined, x's sequence $a_n$ is either equivalent to 0-sequence or not. In the former case, we have $x = 0$ ***(Case 1)***. In the latter case, since $a_n$ is ***not*** equivalent to 0-sequence, there exists a positive rational $\delta$ such that: $|a_i - 0| = |a_i| > \delta$ for all $i \geq 1$. Since $x$ is a real number, the sequence $a_n$ is Cauchy. So it is $\frac{\delta}{2}$-steady for some $N$. But since there is some $i$ such that $|a_i|>\delta$, we have: 
$$ \delta \lt |a_i| \\ = |a_i - 0| \\ \leq |a_i - a_j| + |a_j - 0| \\ \leq \frac{\delta}{2} + |a_j| $$Thus, for a fixed $a_i \gt \delta$, we have $a_j \gt \frac{\delta}{2}$ for all $i, j \geq N$. For a fixed $i$ and any $j$, we are now left with four cases:

1. $a_i \gt \delta \gt 0$.

   - If $a_j \gt \frac{\delta}{2} \gt 0$: In this case, for all $n \geq N$,
     $a_n \gt 0$. A sequence where $b_n := \delta$ for all $n \lt N$ and
     $b_n := a_n$ for all $n \geq N$ is positively bounded away from
     zero, and is equivalent to the original sequence $a_n$, making $x =
        LIM_{n \to \inf} a_n$ a positive value. ***(Case 2)***
   - If $a_j \leq -\frac{\delta}{2} \lt 0$: Then $|a_i - a_j| \gt \frac{\delta}{2}$ which is a contradiction.
2. $a_i \lt -\delta \lt 0$ and $a_j \lt -\frac{\delta}{2} \lt 0$. We can generate an equivalent sequence negatively bounded away from zero, thus making x a negative value ***(Case 3)***. When $a_i \lt 0$, $a_j$ cannot be positive, as it would contradict $\frac{\delta}{2}$-steadiness.

None of $a_n$ can be zero since $x$ is a non-zero real number.